# Which sequences $d_1,\ldots,d_n$ guarantee the planarity of a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Which sequences

$$d_1,\ldots,d_n$$

$$d_1\le \cdots\le d_n$$

have the property, that every graph with this degree sequence is planar ?

It is clear that every sequence with $d_n\le 2$ works. As for the related question
 asking which sequences are graphical-planar, I only found links but without concrete
 classifications.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/119887/37212